# Slim Framework - get all headers

Tags: php, slim

I discovered Slim yesterday and really like it.  I have run into some minor issues.  Here is one:

I would like to send out extra headers from my jQuery UI app to my Slim REST API.  Not a problem at the jQuery end- $.ajax provides that capability.  However, I thought I would write up a small Slim app to test out Slim's own ability to give me access to all request headers.  Here is that app

```
function indexFunction()
{
 global $app;
 $headers = $app->request->headers;
echo json_encode($headers);
}

header('Content-type:text/plain');
$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->get("/",'indexFunction');
$app->run();
```

I opened [DHC](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dhc-resthttp-api-client/aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm?hl=en) in Chrome and fired off a GET request

```
http://ipaddr/slimrestapi
```

after adding the header  *xhash = abc123*

For good measure I started up Fiddler and watched the traffic as I sent out that request.  Fiddler faithfully reported  the following headers

```
Host: ipaddr
Connection: keep-alive
xhash: abc123
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,de;q=0.6,fr;q=0.4
```

However, the results echoed back by slim are an empty JSON object, {}.

Am I misunderstanding something here or is there a bug in Slim?  I'd much appreciate any help.

Comment: Anyone have a new answer for the latest version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The headers in Slim are an instance of Slim\Helper\Set
You can get the content as you want with the `all()` function

```
json_encode($app->request()->headers()->all());
```

Or in a full example

```
$app->get('/', function() use ($app) {
    echo json_encode($app->request()->headers()->all());
    echo $app->request()->headers()->get('xhash');
});
```

The example also shows how you can avoid using that `global` statement. This is a good read on that subject http://tomnomnom.com/posts/why-global-state-is-the-devil-and-how-to-avoid-using-it

Comment: Thanks.  Am I just having newbie issues or is the Slim documentation not quite there yet?  I spent a while looking through the docs before posting here and I did not find all(). That apart, use is fine when you want to (ugh...) use anonymous functions but that will soon start getting unwieldy when creating anything but the most trival of REST APIs. A better route to avoiding the global is stick in a  $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
in the first line of each method. That apart - just a personal view - I think using a few judiciously defined globals is not THAT awful.